# Chrome occasionally causes whole computer to temporarily freeze

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, freeze

Sometimes when opening a tab with chrome, my computer will freeze momentarily. The audio of the music I'm playing will skip and the mouse stays where it was until it unfreezes. It only lasts under a second, but happens multiple times in succession and then goes away.

Any idea what the problem is?

edit: This happens too sporadically for me to "try" anything. It rarely happens.

Comment: Does it happen regardless of the content of the new tab? Which Chrome version are you currently using? What extensions do you have installed? Do you get the same issue while using the [incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en)? Also, consider [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us) and/or creating a new user account to see whether it makes any difference.